# SSL errors everytime I fetch or push from/to Github

Tags: terminal, network, homebrew, ssl

I've been having this issue the past few days and I don't know where the issue is coming from.

When I try to `brew update`, or pull anything from git, I get this error:

```
➜ brew update
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/adoptopenjdk/homebrew-openjdk/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/': LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443
...
```

In order to temporarily fix the issue, I need to reboot my computer. Does anybody know where the problem would be coming from?

TIA

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48987512/ssl-connect-ssl-error-syscall-in-connection-to-github-com443. The most upvoted answer recommends disabling IPv6 with this command: `networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi`.

Comment: Are any VPN or [proxy configurations](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/102427/5472) or software  in use on your Mac?  Please edit details in the question if so.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use Kaspersky Antivirus?

Try disabling it. It's known to cause that issue (see [Random failing of SSL (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) in macOS Mojave](https://superuser.com/questions/1417687/random-failing-of-ssl-ssl-error-syscall-in-macos-mojave), for example).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).